# sass how to make image scale with screen?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have an image within a div like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="text">blah</div> // width 50%
    <div class="image">
        <img src="image.jpg"> // width 80%; some margin
    </div> // width 50%
</div>

-----------------------------
|             |   _______   |
|             |  |       |  |
|     50%     |  |       |  |
|     text    |  | image |  |
|             |  |       |  |
-----------------------------
```

The problem is that the image has to be absolute and bottom:0 while keeping the ratio, but the text's font-size won't change. So it will look pretty bad and unpredictable on a large screen:

```
                           _______
                          |       |
--------------------------|       |------
|        50%        |     | image |     |
|        text       |     |       |     |
-----------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to do the smart scaling job in sass?

Comment: did you try the object-fit:contain css property?

Comment: Thank you! I think this works

Comment: object-fit doesn't work with any of the IE stuff, I'd look into [media queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)